# Odoo 10 - Search method

Tags: python, odoo

I don't understand why here it works :

```
# Fonction qui récupère la valeur du champs booléen inscription de l'année précédente
    @api.depends('half_pension')
    def _retrieve_halfpension_previous(self):
        records = self.env['ecole.partner.school'].search([])
        for record in records:
            record.half_pension_previous = record.half_pension
```

And here, i have a error expected singleton:

```
# Fonction qui récupère la valeur du champs booléen inscription de l'année précédente
    @api.depends('half_pension')
    def _retrieve_halfpension_previous(self):
        records = self.env['ecole.partner.school'].search([('id', '<', self.id)])
        for record in records:
            record.half_pension_previous = record.half_pension
```

Why ?

Thanks You

Comment: it's been a while since working with odoo, but what about using the multiple @annotation?

 @api.multi('half_pension')

Comment: I didn't get what you are trying to do in your code !!!

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are using `self.id` where self is a recordset containing more than one value. Normally to solve it you need to iterate the recordset in self to access every record field like this:

```
@api.depends('half_pension')
def _retrieve_halfpension_previous(self):
    for rec in self:
        records = self.env['ecole.partner.school'].search([('id', '<', rec.id)])
        for record in records:
            record.half_pension_previous = record.half_pension
```

But in this case it will be ok to find the max id of the records in self to use it in just one search, like:

```
@api.depends('half_pension')
def _retrieve_halfpension_previous(self):
    max_id = max([rec.id for rec in self])
    records = self.env['ecole.partner.school'].search([('id', '<', max_id)])
    for record in records:
        record.half_pension_previous = record.half_pension
```